# Apply function only if columns respect condition

Tags: r, function, class, loops, if-statement

I’m new to R and I’m trying to learn fundamentals. I’m facing a small problem for which I can’t find a solution online.

What I want to do: write a function to lower case for all the columns in my `data.frame` if they respect a condition `(class = factor)`

This code works, but for all my columns :

```
lower = function(x) { data.frame(tolower(as.matrix(x))) }
```

I need more something like this, but it doesn’t work:

```
lower = function (x) { 
  for (i in 1:length(x)) {
    if (class(i)=="factor") {
         data.frame(tolower(as.matrix(x))) 
    }
  }
}
```

`x` is my `data.frame`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about  [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  and how to give a  [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) . This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your attempt is close, but the returning is the tricky part. Since there is no sample data, here is an example using `iris` and changing to upper case instead:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(head(iris), function(x){
  if(class(x) == "factor"){
    return(toupper(x))
  } else{
    return(x)
  }
}))
```

`lapply` is an efficient way to loop through list data (and a data.frame is inherently a list). `as.data.frame` is necessary to convert back to a data.frame.

However, there are even better tools available to avoid writing them yourself, including `mutate_if` from `dplyr`:

```
head(iris) %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, toupper)
```

Both of these return:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  SETOSA
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  SETOSA
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  SETOSA
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  SETOSA
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  SETOSA
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  SETOSA
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mark !! Your answer is clear and simple :)

Comment: The value returned by `toupper` or `tolower` is always a character vector, regardless of what you run it through.

Comment: Yes Mark, you should be aware of the side effects of any manipulations.

Comment: No argument there. Your answer does return a factor, though OP's initial code did not, and that was not a stated requirement. My non-dplyr solution only returns a factor due to the default of `stringsAsFactor` and the levels will not (necessarily) match up to the intial levels. The question, more broadly, is about applying functions to subset of columns; the behavior of that function is a separate (important) issue

Answer (score 1):

Note that the solutions to the question below return factor columns as factor and do not re-order the factor levels.

> The approach in the question could re-order factor levels because that
>   code changes the factor columns to character and then back to factor
>   using default ordering (which may not have been the initial ordering).
>   For example, this shows what can happen if `tolower` is applied
>   directly to a factor:
>
> ```
> fac <- factor(c("One", "None", "Two"), levels = c("One", "Two", "None"))
>
> fac
> ## [1] One  None Two 
> ## Levels: One Two None
>
> factor(tolower(fac)) # order of levels has changed!
> ## [1] one  none two 
> ## Levels: none one two
> ```
>
> In particular, that implies that `sort(fac)` does not correspond to
>   the order in `sort(factor(tolower(fac)))` .

We now discuss some alternative solutions to the question which do not have the reordering problem.

**1)** Create a function `lc_lev` which lower cases levels of a factor and passes the input through unchanged if not a factor.  Then lapply it over the columns of the input -- here we use the built in CO2 -- and change it back to a data.frame of the same shape:

```
lc_lev <- function(x) {
  if (is.factor(x)) levels(x) <- tolower(levels(x))
  x
}

replace(CO2, TRUE, lapply(CO2, lc_lev))
```

**1a)** This would also work:

```
CO2[] <- lapply(CO2, lc_lev)
```

**2)** Another approach is to use S3.  The generic (first line) dispatches to the factor method if the input is a factor and to the default method otherwise:

```
lc_lev2 <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("lc_lev2")
lc_lev2.factor <- function(x) { levels(x) <- tolower(levels(x)); x }
lc_lev2.default <- identity

CO2[] <- lapply(CO2, lc_lev2)
```